# Using index to replace several levels of factor

Tags: r

I am interested in finding the most efficient way to replace several levels of a factor in a data frame, using an index..... below is an example of the data frame I called it "ph2", the index "index", and my approach which is not so efficient especially when we have a large number of replacements.

```
index <- data.frame(
   AA = LETTERS[seq( from = 1, to = 5 )],
   BB = c("x1","x2","x3","x4","x5")
    )


ph2 <- data.frame(
    name = LETTERS[seq( from = 1, to = 5 )],
    RE = seq(1:5))


levels(ph2$name)[levels(ph2$name)=="A"] <- "X1"
levels(ph2$name)[levels(ph2$name)=="B"] <- "X2"
levels(ph2$name)[levels(ph2$name)=="C"] <- "X3"
levels(ph2$name)[levels(ph2$name)=="D"] <- "X4"
levels(ph2$name)[levels(ph2$name)=="E"] <- "X5"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
levels(ph2$name) <- paste0("X",ph2$RE[match(levels(ph2$name),ph2$name)])
levels(ph2$name)
#[1] "X1" "X2" "X3" "X4" "X5"
```

Or if they're well sorted already as they are here :

```
levels(ph2$name) <- paste0("X",ph2$RE)
```

Comment: Thank you --- I am looking for a more generic way,...  X here is just an example ... it could be any character or name in order or not.

Comment: I don't understand your general case then

Comment: Then you might want to look closer to the first position, this is what it does, `match` gives you the index of the first input in the vector you provide as a second input